# How to use map to calculate a function with more than one parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, mapreduce

.i have a classifier function:

```
def f(x, threshold):
if logi == 1:
    if x > threshold:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

and there is a list a=[2, 3, 12, 4, 53, 3],if use map(f(threshold=4),a) will raise error "f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'"
but if i specify threshold default 4,it will work. Modify function definition as

```
def f(x, threshold=4):
if logi == 1:
    if x > threshold:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
map(f,a)
```

will have expected result [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],i would like to know if there is some method can reach the same goal without specify parameter default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i would like to know if there is some method can reach the same goal
>   without specify parameter default? thanks in advance!

There sure is!, a few ways really.
Personally i'd use a list comprehension since they are so readable. Like this:

```
def f(x, threshold, logi=1):
    if logi == 1:
        if x > threshold:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    else:
        if x < threshold:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

a=[2, 3, 12, 4, 53, 3]

x = [f(item, 4) for item in a]
print(x)
#output =>  [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Hope this helps :)

If you're set on map then perhaps functools will help:

```
from functools import partial
mapfunc = partial(f, 4)
(map(mapfunc, a))
```

Comment: is there method to reach the gold using function map?

Comment: @martin perhaps functools partial is what you're looking for, is an import okay?

Answer (score 0):

`map`supports accepting multiple iterables, stopping when the shortest is exhausted, passing the output of each as sequential postional arguments to the mapper function. If you have a single, fixed argument, you can use `itertools.repeat` to produce it over and over, e.g.:

```
from itertools import repeat

map(f, a, repeat(4))
```

This approach generalizes to more complex scenarios, allowing cycling a fixed set of values (`itertools.cycle`), or just pairing two iterables as with `zip`, but without needing to `zip` and then `itertools.starmap` the tuples back to positional arguments.

Another approach that's specifically useful for a constant argument is partial binding with `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial
map(partial(f, threshold=4), a)
```

where `partial` creates a new (C-level in CPython) wrapper function that will pass the provided arguments to the wrapped function when not explicitly overridden.